# How to trace page behind the scene?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to trace page behind the scene? And send all tracing information by email?
**not to show any tracing information on client side.**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to implement a custom trace listener, in this case an SMTP trace listener, a sample implementation can be found here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/smtptracelistenerarticle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could look into various logging frameworks for .NET. A popular one is [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), which will allow you to keep track of any errors in your application and email you the logs. You can see a comparison chart of some logging frameworks [here](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/comparison/).